# Thevenin resistance in a fault current

Tags: thevenin, reactance

In the reactance diagram, why is j0.20 (as circled in the picture) in series with j0.20 + j0.10 + j0.17. Why isn't j0.20 (circled) in parallel with j0.20 + j0.10 + j0.17 and j0.20 + j0.1333 + j0.24.

[image]

Comment: They look to me like they are wired in series so why shouldn't they be calculated as in series?

Comment: In that case, why can't we say that the reactance is in series with j0.20 + j0.1333 + j0.24?

Comment: I'm not pretending to understand completely the diagram you posted and I don't understand what fault condition might lead to that situation; I'm just looking at it as a circuit with components.

Comment: Actually, I didn’t see the brackets properly in the solution. That j0.20 is actually in series when you take the parallel of the other two branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all of your voltage sources are equal in per unit (1.0).  Re-draw your circuit so you only have one source pushing current through those three branches (tie all of your three sources positive terminals together).  When you do that, and then re-draw the circuit, it will become crystal clear.